# Exporting data from R to Excel: formulas do not recalculate

Tags: r, excel

R(3.0.2) / MSOffice 2013 / Win7

Assume we have an existing data.xlsx file with two sheets - "data" and "calc".

"data" sheet is filled through R with:

```
require(XLConnect)
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(2,3,4,5,6))
wb <- loadWorkbook("data.xlsx", create=F)
setStyleAction(wb, type=XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.NONE")
writeWorksheet(wb, data=df, sheet="data", startRow=1, startCol=1, header=F)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

So here comes the problem - I have "calc" sheet that refers to "data" sheet with formulas. For some reason updating the data doesn't get recalculated even though formulas refer to cells that were just filled in.

Calculation option in Excel is turned to automatic, even turning it to manual and pressing F9 to force for recalculation doesn't work.

I've found some odd ways to make this work: 1. select particular cell which has proper formula in it and press enter (for each and every cell) 2. drag formulas over malfunctioning cells over again (overwrite formula with the exact same formula..) 3. Refering to data sheet from other file (say, data2.xlsx) does work but this for me is a last resort option. I don't want to bloat file structure with separate data files. Plus, consider this horrible requirement of opening both file in order to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can reproduce this exact problem with Excel2010 on Win7.  My recommendation is to file a bug report with the author of XLConnect and in the meantime to try working with the `xlsx` package instead. BTW, I tried skipping your `setStyleAction` line, with no change in the results.  I think something in XLConnect is breaking whatever Excel uses to "link" formulas to their referenced cells.

Comment: I remember struggling with xlsx package too and choosing XLConnect was for a good reason... Guess I will have to try it again and post back what I get. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I have this problem routinely. I do not know if xlsx has the same problem. I _do_ know that if I use older file formats (.xls) the formulas will recalc for me. I have sometimes resorted to writing the formulas myself from XLConnect, but that's a rather tedious solution. I agree that this is something that the XLConnect devs should address.

Comment: @joran Which really should be one more reason for all of us to stop using Excel entirely :-( .

Comment: I can reproduce the problem using Excel for Mac 2011 using XLConnect 0.2-5

Comment: Wish I could stop using Excel.. but problem is that I'm writing an automated database update script for users that are familiar only with office tools. So only database itself can be touched. For now it seems like I will have to resort to using separate files for database and calculations. Will also write a bug report to XLConnect authors.

Comment: Formula recalculation in Excel is a tricky topic and depends on file format, Excel version, settings and user session. See for example the following MS KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214395/en-us or the following MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx

Comment: XLConnect comes along with a method setForceFormulaRecalculation which controls a flag that forces Excel to recalculate formula values when a workbook is opened. But again, the actual behavior depends on a number of factors as stated above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking that this link gets some clicks and solution is hidden in comments section, here's the answer:

`wb$setForceFormulaRecalculation(T)`

This should work for most of packages (at least ones based on rJava) as this java method is passed within excel, hence is not determined by R language.

Answer (score 1):

After you load a workbook and write in data, force a formula recalculation before saving the workbook to a directory.

This should work for you:

```
writeWorksheet(wb, data=df, sheet="data", startRow=1, startCol=1, header=F)
setForceFormulaRecalculation(wb,"data",TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is 2.5 years old, but I just had exact same issue with you. I suspect there are some issues with XLConnect. I used `write.csv` and it worked. The problem I have with `write.csv` is that my dataframe has more than 16384 columns and I can't add another sheet to the file.

Comment: Yeah I'm experiencing it as well

Answer (score -1):

You can put this VBA macro in a module of your excel document and run (from excel) it after your data transfer.

```
    Sub RefreshCalculations()
        Calculate
    End Sub
```

Even simplest: press F9 in excel, this forces calculation of all formulas.

I'm sorry for my previous answer.

this macro works for me, just tested:

```
Sub refresh2()
Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim rng0 As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim c As Range

'loop through the sheets
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    'limit the search to the UsedRange
    Set rng0 = sht.UsedRange
    On Error Resume Next ' in case of no formulas

    'reduce looping further
    Set rng1 = rng0.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

    For Each c In rng1 'loop through the SpecialCells only
        c.Formula = c.Formula
    Next

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That is not what the OP said:  he already tried this, as did I.  The problem is deeper than just a recalculation.

Comment: I suspect that macro is pretty much the same as pressing F9. And... I think I already mentioned trying this in the post.

Comment: That's a very creative work-around, but I have two objections. First, it's likely to run amok if there are other formulas in the worksheet.  Second, as it's pretty clear `XLConnect` is doing something that `xlsx`-type workbooks don't like, it's the `R`-package which should be fixed, rather than allowing a mistake to propogate.

Comment: @Carl Witthof, yes, I agree with you, it's a workaround but you have to understand excel. Excel is a front end software, the calculation mechanism triggers only when you put some data in the cell by keypad. So the workaround works 'touching' each formula in the worksheet. And, sorry if I insists, my macro solves the problem or not?

Comment: I don't really want to add an unnecessary level of complexity to product that is meant to be used (and accidentally misused) by non-experienced users. I assume if this script touches every cell, it is a valid workaround. But it is not really a solution since creating excel files is and should be an easy and non-problematic task. +1 for creativity though.

Comment: @A. Val. Excel is the unnecessary level of complexity. R has enough packages to do whatever you want, charts, documents in any form, database interfaces, why do you need excel? If you want to use excel, I think, you have to accept some agreement with it. Excel, I repeat, is a front-end software and not designed as "engine". As an alternative you can solve your problem preparing a text file and loading it into excel or waiting for XLConnect next release. My best.

Comment: Lets not drive this conversation into subjectivity. Not every user is proficient with tools beyond spreadsheets like MS Office.